# Getter function not returning proper value

Tags: java, android, baseadapter, getter-setter

I am new to android. I am developing an app. I am have data in json format which I wan to show in listview. I am using baseadapter and setters and getters. But getter function returns the same value  which was last set. Here is my code.

```
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
     pojo = new Pojo();
     for (int k = 0; k < arr.length(); k++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj1 = arr.getJSONObject(k);
            date = jsonObj1.optString("login_date");
            inTime = jsonObj1.optString("login_time");
            outTime = jsonObj1.optString("logout_time");
            pojo.setDate(date);
            pojo.setLoginTime(inTime);
            pojo.setLogoutTime(outTime);
            Log.e("history activity date", "" + date);
            Log.e("history  intime", "" + inTime);
            Log.e("history  outtime", "" + outTime);
            history.add(pojo);
       }
    }
```

This is how i am setting adapter in postExecute() method

```
     myAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(HistoryActivity.this, history);
     list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

My setter and getter functions

```
  public void setLoginTime(String loginTime) {
    this.loginTime = loginTime;
    Log.e("Settter loginTime",""+loginTime);
}

public String getLoginTime() {
    Log.e("getter loginTime",""+loginTime);
    return loginTime;

}

public void setLogoutTime(String logoutTime) {

    this.logoutTime = logoutTime;
    Log.e("Settter logoutTime",""+logoutTime);
}

public String getLogoutTime() {
    Log.e("getter loginTime",""+logoutTime);
    return logoutTime;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
    Log.e("Settter date",""+date);
}

public String getDate() {
    Log.e("getter date",""+date);
    return date;
}
```

And this adapter

```
  public class HistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context activity;
TextView datetime;
TextView inTime;
TextView outTime;


Pojo pojo;
ArrayList<Pojo> list;
private ArrayList<Pojo> arraylist=null;
public static LayoutInflater inflater;

public HistoryAdapter(Context a, ArrayList<Pojo> history){
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    activity=a;
    list=history;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(list);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_item, parent, false);
    pojo = list.get(position);
    datetime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.historyDate);
    datetime.setText(pojo.getDate());
    inTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.historyLoginTime);
    inTime.setText(pojo.getLoginTime());
    outTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.historyLogoutTime);
    outTime.setText(pojo.getLogoutTime());
    return v;

}

 }
```

This is my json

```
  [{"login_time":"16:18:39","logout_time":"16:24:45","login_date":"2015-10-01"},{"login_time":"11:46:56","logout_time":"11:52:08","login_date":"2015-10-03"},{"login_time":"16:10:34","logout_time":"16:10:53","login_date":"2015-10-06"},{"login_time":"16:26:26","logout_time":"16:26:59","login_date":"2015-10-06"},{"login_time":"17:13:54","logout_time":"17:14:16","login_date":"2015-10-06"},{"login_time":"18:58:08","logout_time":"19:05:03","login_date":"2015-10-06"},{"login_time":"16:20:49","logout_time":"20:12:57","login_date":"2015-10-06"}]
```

**UPDATE**

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
 for (int k = 0; k < arr.length(); k++) {
        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
        JSONObject jsonObj1 = arr.getJSONObject(k);
       date = jsonObj1.optString("login_date");
       inTime = jsonObj1.optString("login_time");
       outTime = jsonObj1.optString("logout_time");

       pojo.setDate(date);
       pojo.setLoginTime(inTime);
       pojo.setLogoutTime(outTime);
       Log.e("history activity date", "" + date);
       Log.e("history  intime", "" + inTime);
       Log.e("history  outtime", "" + outTime);
       history.add(pojo);
     }
```

Please help me... Thanks

Comment: "But getter function returns the same value which was last set." That's what getters normally do. Your question would be a lot better if you'd cut the code down to a still-complete but *minimal* example... but if you increased the explanation of what you're trying to achieve and what's actually happening.

Comment: Use Gson for this, Just a suggestion

Answer (score 2):

It is because here:

```
  pojo = new Pojo();
  for (int k = 0; k < arr.length(); k++) {
```

you are simply changing over and over the same `Pojo` reference, while you want to add a new instance at every iteration:

```
  for (int k = 0; k < arr.length(); k++) {
    pojo = new Pojo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
for (int k = 0; k < arr.length(); k++) {
    JSONObject jsonObj1 = arr.getJSONObject(k);
    date = jsonObj1.optString("login_date");
    inTime = jsonObj1.optString("login_time");
    outTime = jsonObj1.optString("logout_time");
    pojo = new Pojo();
    pojo.setDate(date);
    pojo.setLoginTime(inTime);
    pojo.setLogoutTime(outTime);
    Log.e("history activity date", "" + date);
    Log.e("history  intime", "" + inTime);
    Log.e("history  outtime", "" + outTime);
    history.add(pojo);
}
```

It may be happening as you are not creating or reassigning your pojo object in the for loop. for each new set of values you should create a new object of your getter setter class that is your `POJO` class.

Answer (score 0):

You use `pojo = new Pojo();` once and use `history.add(pojo);`,so `history` only contains a reference list to same pojo.

Comment: No proper explaination

Comment: Thanks,not a reference,is a reference list to a same object.

Answer (score 0):

In you **Pojo** class , add 3 arguments **constructor** and use below code .

```
for (int k = 0; k < arr.length(); k++) {
   Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
   JSONObject jsonObj1 = arr.getJSONObject(k);
   String date = jsonObj1.optString("login_date");
   String inTime = jsonObj1.optString("login_time");
   String outTime = jsonObj1.optString("logout_time");

   history.add(new Pojo(jsonObj1.optString("login_date"),jsonObj1.optString("login_time"),jsonObj1.optString("logout_time")));
   history.add(pojo);
 }
```

Comment: can u put ur updated code ? btw inside ur getView() method , can u try putting **Pojo pojo = list.get(position);** instead

Comment: I have added the update. I have even tried using this in adapter but that also dont work

Comment: can u help me , to dump **history** list once the adapter is constructed and see the data are same in log ?

Comment: Yes the data is same in adapter

Comment: in **for** loop , you already print out the **date / inTime /outTime **, check those data are correct one . If those are correct , try my updated answer .. :-)